# apache reverse proxy - make static content cachable

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, tomcat6, mod-cache

I have an apache web server (reverse proxy with mod_proxy) in a front of a tomcat java application. to improve performance, i would like to make static content (css, javascript and images) cachable using mod_cache and mod_disk_cache.

my question is : can i use mod_headers and mod_expires in apache web server to modify content headers so it will be cached by apache?

thanks